# JQuery: Cannot pass value to a Select Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I don't seem to find a way to pass the value of a drop down list to a select query that's in another page. For some reason it works to populate the drop down boxes, but not to filter the comments by topic ID.
I am trying to pass the selected value of the sTopic select list to fetch_comment dot php in order to only retrieve comments that match the selected thread_id.

To be more specific this is the piece of code that is not working.

```
var sTopic = $(this).val()
$.post( "fetch_comment.php", { idTopic: sTopic } );
```

index dot php

```
<?php
//index.php
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Topic Tracker</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="./css/doc.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <h2 align="center"><a href="#">Topic Tracker</a></h2>
  <br />

      <div class="container" style="margin-top:35px">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sYear">Year</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sYear" name="sYear"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sTopic">Topic</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="sTopic" name="sTopic" disabled></select>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="alert alert-info" id="alert_info"></div>
    </div>


  <div class="container" style="margin-top:35px">
    <div class="bd-callout bd-callout-warning" id="rule_abstract">
        <h4 id="conveying-meaning-to-assistive-technologies">Proposed Rule Change Abstract</h4>
        <p id="rule_text"></p>   
    </div> 

    <div class="bd-callout bd-callout-warning" id="proposed_rule">
        <h4 id="conveying-meaning-to-assistive-technologies">Proposed Rule Text</h4>
        <p id="rule_text_proposed"></p>   
    </div>
   </div>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:35px">
   <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <h2>Comment Section</h2>
     <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="thread_id" id="thread_id" value="1" />
     <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <span id="comment_message"></span>
   <br />
   <div id="display_comment"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<?php $GLOBALS['a'] = '1'; ?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide Alert Info
    $("#alert_info").hide();
    //Hide Rule Abstract
    $("#rule_abstract").hide();
    //Hide Proposed Rule Text
    $("#proposed_rule").hide();
    //Hide Comment Form
    $("#comment_form").hide();   
    //Hide Comments
    $("#display_comment").hide();     
    //Get the dropdowns ready
    $.get('data.php',function(fyear){
        $('#sYear').html(fyear)
    })
    $('#sYear').change(function(){
        $('#sTopic').removeAttr('disabled')
        var sYear = $(this).val()
        $.post('data.php?p=sTopic',{idYear:sYear},function(ftopic){
            $('#sTopic').html(ftopic)
        })
        $("#alert_info").hide();
        $("#rule_abstract").hide();
        $("#proposed_rule").hide();
        $("#comment_added_success").hide();
        $("#comment_form").hide();
        $("#display_comment").hide()        

    })

    $('#sTopic').change(function(){
        var sTopic = $(this).val()
        $.post( "fetch_comment.php", { idTopic: sTopic } );

        var info = 'Year: '+ $('#sYear').val() +', Topic '+ $('#sTopic').val()
        $('.alert').html(info)
        $("#alert_info").show();
        $("#rule_abstract").show();
        $("#proposed_rule").show();
        $("#comment_form").show();
        $("#display_comment").show(); 
        $("#comment_added_success").show();
        $('#rule_text').html(info);
        $('#rule_text_proposed').html(info)       
    })


     //Submit Comment
     $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var form_data = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
       url:"add_comment.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:form_data,
       dataType:"JSON",
       success:function(data)
       {
        if(data.error != '')
        {
         $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
         $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
         $('#comment_id').val('0');
         load_comment();
        }
       }
      })
     });

    load_comment();
    //Load Comments
    function load_comment()
    {   
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch_comment.php",
       method:"POST",
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('#display_comment').html(data);
       }
      })
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
      var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
      $('#comment_name').focus();
     });     
});
</script>
```

data dot php

```
$page = isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : '' ;
if($page=='sTopic'){
    $sYear = $_POST['idYear'];
    echo "<option selected disabled>Select Topic</option>";
    $query = $connect->prepare("select * from tbl_topics where id_year='$sYear'");
    $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_topic'] ?>"><?php echo $row['st_topic'] ?></option>
        <?php
    }

} else{
    echo "<option selected disabled>Select Year</option>";
    $query = $connect->prepare("select * from tbl_years");
    $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id_year'] ?>"><?php echo $row['tp_year'] ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

fetch_comment dot php

```
//fetch_comment.php

//----------------------------
// Connect to database
//----------------------------
require("dbconfig.php"); 

$sTopic= "";
$sTopic = $_POST['idTopic'];

$query = "
SELECT * FROM tbl_comments 
WHERE thread_id = '".$sTopic."'
AND parent_comment_id = '0'
ORDER BY comment_id DESC
";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $output .= '
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
  <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Reply</button></div>
 </div>
 ';
 $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"]);
}

echo $output;

function get_reply_comment($connect, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0)
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM tbl_comments WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'
 ";
 $output = '';
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
 if($parent_id == 0)
 {
  $marginleft = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
 }
 if($count > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '
   <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:'.$marginleft.'px">
    <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> on <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
    <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
    <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Reply</button></div>
   </div>
   ';
   $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);
  }
 }
 return $output;
}
?>
```

Not posting add_comment.php since it is working perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is sending the value as expected. But now the #display_comment div is not visible. If I remove dataType:'json', the #display_commment div is shown, but of course not with the results I want, since the idTopic is not being sent.

```
//Load Comments
function load_comment()
{   
  var sTopic = $('#sTopic option:selected').val()
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   dataType:'json',
   data: ({idTopic: sTopic}),
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
    console.log(data);
   }
  })
}
```